# Linq version of the simulated annealing algorithm

Tags: c#, linq

I decided to try and implement (a version of) the [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) algorithm using just LINQ, just to see if I could.

I'd love it if anybody could see any ways to improve it, or give advice on any cool tricks for doing this kind of thing.

```
var result = (from res in Enumerable.Range(0, 1)
                  let R = new Random()
                  let initial = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => R.Next(-10, 10))
                  let iterations = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)

                  let Schedule = (Func<int, float>)
                                 (X => 4 + (float)Math.Sin(X))


                  from iteration in iterations
                      let temperature = Schedule(iteration)
                      let state = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => R.Next(-10, 10))
                      let DeltaE = state.Sum() - initial.Sum()

                      where DeltaE > 0 ||
                            Math.Pow(Math.E, DeltaE / temperature) > R.NextDouble()
                      select state.ToList()
              ).OrderBy(S => S.Sum()).First();
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a lot of small errors here.

- What is the purpose of `from res in Enumerable.Range(0, 1)`? It looks like you did it to force some local variables into 'let' queries, which makes no sense to me.
- Instead of using `OrderBy(X).First()` you should use `MinBy(X)` (write it yourself if it doesn't exist). There's a significant performance difference.
- The value of `initial` changes every time it is enumerated. Confusing. (You can cache the results with `ToArray` or `ToList` to prevent re-enumerating from running more `Random.Next` calls)
- Ensure `new Random()` is only performed once (do it outside the query). The default seed is the current time, which is highly correlated between calls. You're likely to end up with two instances of `Random` with the exact same seed.
- `Random.Next(-10, 10)` returns values in `[-10, +9]`. You probably wanted `[-10, +10]`.